# how to close a form with a string

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Hey guys I have got to a head scratcher well at least for me any way. I need to find a way of opening a form with a string. I have got this ...

```
    Dim asm = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly
    Dim myTypes As Type() = asm.GetTypes()
    Dim frm As Form
    For Each t As Type In myTypes
        If t.IsSubclassOf(GetType(System.Windows.Forms.Form)) AndAlso Me.Label4.Text = t.Name Then
            frm = CType(Activator.CreateInstance(t), Form)
            frm.Close()                
            frm.Hide()
        End If
    Next
```

But it doesn't close the program or even hide it i have no clue?

**Question:** "I need to find a way of opening a form with a string"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to do and why are you using reflection

Comment: Well i got that of Google and it was the best one i could find?

Comment: I see what you're trying to do, and I see why it doesn't work.  You're calling frm.Close() on an instance of the form's type, not on the actually open form.  Is the form you are trying to close running in the same application as the above code?

Comment: Yes it is in the same application

Answer (score 1):

That looks to me like you created a new form instance of that type and tried to close/hide it, but I don't see it ever being shown.

If you are trying to close an existing form, then you don't want to create a new instance using Activator.CreateInstance.  Rather you need to somehow locate the existing instance of the form that is already open, and close that specific instance.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted approximates code that would create a new instance of a form by type name, then close/hide the form.

(If you wanted to close an already-open form by name, I would do:

```
For Each f As Form In My.Application.OpenForms
  If f Is My.Forms.NameOfFormThatIWantToClose Then f.Close()
Exit For
```

)

But I thought you wanted to **open** a new form by name. If so, you will need to use reflection. [This page](http://sites.google.com/site/timkeynet/tutorials/VB-Tutorials/loadvbnetformbystringname) seems to do exactly what you want.

Comment: Na i just want any code that will close a open form with a string and i do not know the string. Say i 10 forms and when i click on one it will set a string on my main form and press close on another it will close the one that i previously clicked on.